# Android activity does not respond when tring to stop video recording

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I have started my video recording from an activity. Then, I wished to pause my activity, but it doesn't respond as soon as I try to stop my video recording after resuming the activity.

```
public void recordVideo(View view)
{


Button videoRecordingButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.videorecordingbutton);
Log.d("tag",String.valueOf(isRecording));
if(isRecording==false)
{
   cameraView.prepareVideoRecorder();
   mediaRecorder = cameraView.mMediaRecorder;
    mediaRecorder.start();

    isRecording = true;

videoRecordingButton.setText("Stop");

}
else
{
    Log.d("####","####before mediaRecorder.stop()");

    mediaRecorder.stop();
    Log.d("####","####after mediaRecorder.stop()");
    isRecording = false;
    videoRecordingButton.setText("Start");

}
```